# Induced e.m.f depends on...?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

In my revision guide it says that Michael Faraday did experiments that showed that induced e.m.f for a coil of wire depends on four things:

1. Magnetic strength of the core in the coil of wire. (stronger --> bigger emf)
2. Number of turns of wire in the coil (more turns --> bigger emf)
3. The cross-sectional area of the coil (bigger area --> bigger emf). (This could also be seen as the *angle* you point the magnet at the coil, because flux linkage is basically the same as flux cutting.)
4. How fast you move the magnet into/out of the coil. (Faster --> bigger emf)

But Faraday's law seems to not show all four of these:

$\text{induced emf}=N\frac{\Delta \phi}{\Delta t}$.

(Sorry I don't know calculus yet which is why I didn't use the calculus version)

This equation shows that induced emf only depends on two things:

1. Number of turns of wire $N$.
2. How fast you move the magnet.

Where did the others go? :

3. Area of the coil.
4. Magnetic strength of the core.

Comment: The quantities you are missing determine the actual value of the flux $\phi$, so the hard stuff, like the influence of the magnetic core material and the actual shape of the field, has been tucked away in this version.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Great, thanks! I think this would make a good answer (instead of comment) if you expand it.

Answer (score 2):

$\text{induced emf}=N\frac{\Delta \phi}{\Delta t}$.

where,$\phi $ is the magnetic flux through the coil.

The flux, $\phi $ depends on both the area of the coil, the magnetic field through the coil and the angle between the direction of magnetic field and the area vector of the coil ( area vector is perpendicular to the plane of the coil ). And the equation of magnetic flux goes as  $\phi $ = BAcos$ \theta $. The flux through a coil is changed by changing any one of these parameters.So, the flux has a direct relation to the area of the coil.

A core can increase the magnetic field to many times the strength of the actual field through the coil alone, due to the "magnetic permeability $ \mu $ " of the material where $ \mu $ depends on the "Magnetic strength of the core material". Hence, B depends on the magnetic strength of the core material also.Hence, the magnetic flux too.

Answer (score 0):

Flux = B.A so more A more flux more emf and B depends on the core

Comment: $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and $\vec{A}$ is the area of the loop.